# Regexp_extract from URLs as strings (SQL BigQuery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to extract a string from multiple URLs that all have one thing in common even though they are built differently. Let me give you a few examples:

```
/cz/category/79478/productname
/https://www.store.net/de/category/49448/productname
/https://www.store.net/category/62448/productname
/category/79455/productname
```

I'm using BigQuery and I'm able to write a `Regexp_extract` clause for individual examples, however, I'm looking for one way of extracting the number (as string) after `category/`, (`79478` from the first url). All the addresses have `/category/` part in common so it should be doable from my point of view.

Here's the expression that I've been trying to use:

```
regexp_extract(page_path, '[^category/]+/([^/]+)/')
```

But it doesn't work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: It turned out it works, thank you:)

Answer (score 2):

Use a noncapture group for the leading `/category/`?

```
regexp_extract(page_path, '(?:/category/)([^/]+)')
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/WSIT77/1

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select page_path, regexp_extract(page_path, r'/category/(\d+)/') number
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]